# Restfully filter on time

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am designing restful api using nodejs/express.

- GET /reports (get all reports)
- PUT /reports/23 (update report w/ id 23)
- GET /reports/23 (get report w/ id 23)
- POST /reports (create report)
- DELETE /reports/23 (delete report w/ id 23)

Pretty standard stuff so far right.  Now I would like to filter on time (timestamp property).  Looking around I cannot find any good examples of restful filtering on time.  Anyone got any good examples.

Best I have come up with is:
/reports?start=2013-07-13&stop=2013-7-14

Which is ok, except for then I would have to assume either <= or < and > or >= and cannot express in a query something different.

Is there a good way to represent the following queries?

- timestamp > 2013-07-13 && timestamp < 2013-07-14
- timestamp >= 2013-07-13 && timestamp < 2013-07-14
- timestamp > 2013-07-13 && timestamp <= 2013-07-14
- timestamp >= 2013-07-13 && timestamp <= 2013-07-14

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing `> or >=` like expressions are not a good REST design. I would suggest to use different query parameters like
startDate - to represent the starting date of the requested filter
duration - beginning from the startDate in terms of Days. Then your requests will look like

```
timestamp > 2013-07-13 && timestamp < 2013-07-14 ---  startDate=2013-07-13&duration=0
timestamp >= 2013-07-13 && timestamp < 2013-07-14 --- startDate=2013-07-13&duration=1
timestamp > 2013-07-13 && timestamp <= 2013-07-14 --- startDate=2013-07-14&duration=1
timestamp >= 2013-07-13 && timestamp <= 2013-07-14--- startDate=2013-07-13&duration=2
```

The query parameters for REST API should be clearly defining the purpose.